# How do I handle onSaveInstanceState for fragments correctly?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, bundle, android-lifecycle

I have an `onSaveInstanceState` method in one fragment `OwnershipFragment` defined as:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    for(int i = 0; i <mDirectors.size(); i++)
        mDirectors.get(i).updateFromForm();

    outState.putSerializable(DIRECTORS, mDirectors);
}
```

However, when I go back to the previous fragment `HomeFragment`,`OwnershipFragment` is put on the back stack, but if I turn my phone/change orientation, the `onSaveInstanceState` of `OwnershipFragment` is still called.

The problem is, since `onSaveInstanceState` is called for `OwnershipFragment`, I get a `nullpointerexception` on `mDirectors` since it was never initialized since `OwnershipFragment` never had `onCreateView` called (seeing as it's in the back stack).

So how do I handle this correctly?

I'm guessing I have to implement `onSaveInstanceState` in my Activity that runs the fragment transactions, but I'm not sure how to go about doing so.

This is the method called to replace the fragments in `HomeActivity`:

```
public void displayView(int position) {

    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (position) {

    case HOME:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;

    case OWNERSHIP:
        fragment = new OwnershipFragment();
        break;

    }
        //Replace fragment
        FragmentTransaction ft = mManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.home_container, fragment, FRAGMENT_TAG);
        ft.addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
}
```

And here's my logcat:

```
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at com.opendoors.core.OwnershipFragment.onSaveInstanceState(OwnershipFragment.java:204)
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at android.app.Fragment.performSaveInstanceState(Fragment.java:1840)
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1598)
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState(FragmentManager.java:1655)
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at android.app.Activity.onSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1233)
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:546)
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at com.opendoors.core.HomeActivity.onSaveInstanceState(HomeActivity.java:220)
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1181)
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1233)
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3778)
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:152)
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1288)
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
07-15 11:28:24.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Could I have the reason this was downvoted so I can correct what's wrong?

Comment: sounds strange, I believe onSaveInstanceState() will never call if fragment didn't instantiation.

Comment: I debugged, and the for loop is indeed where I get the `NullPointerExcetion`, despite the fact that the fragment isn't the current one.

Answer (score 0):

have you create the OwnershipFragment but never attach to the window? if you extended from the `support.Fragment`, you can override the **setUserVisibleHint()** method to check was your fragment really come visible to user.

```
public class OwnershipFragment extend android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    ...
    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
            System.out.println("VISIBLE");
        } else {
            System.out.println("GONE");
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

I think you call the `displayView()` twice with difference position, therefore you couldn't see OwnershipFragment but it actually created, so debug in that method, make it won't call wrong.